# How to extract substrings with delimiters from a string in php

Tags: php

I would like to remove substrings from a string that have delimiters.

Example:

```
$string = "Hi, I want to buy an [apple] and a [banana].";
```

How do I get "apple" and "banana" out of this string and in an array? And the other parts of the string "Hi, I want to buy an" and "and a" in another array.

I apologize if this question has already been answered. I searched this site and couldn't find anything that would help me. Every situation was just a little different.

Comment: What do you mean _And the other parts of the string  in an array_?  You want the words to be values in an array?

Comment: Sorry. Didn't see the question. I want the parts of the phrases in another array. So "Hi, I want to buy an", "and a", "."

Comment: People with quality answers are going to look back at your question history, just FYI

Answer (score 1):

You could use `preg_split()` thus:

```
<?php
$pattern = '/[\[\]]/';  // Split on either [ or ]
$string = "Hi, I want to buy an [apple] and a [banana].";
echo print_r(preg_split($pattern, $string), true);
```

which outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Hi, I want to buy an
    [1] => apple
    [2] =>  and a
    [3] => banana
    [4] => .
)
```

You can trim the whitespace if you like and/or ignore the final fullstop.

Comment: Thanks Dave! This looks exactly like what I want. Going to try it out!

Comment: @WandaEmbar Thought you wanted them in an array and then the "others' in another array?

Comment: @WandaEmbar Might want to respond to comments to the question asking for clarification.

Comment: I can split them into two arrays from here. That's no problem. Thanks so much Dave!

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match_all('(?<=\[)([a-z])*(?=\])', $string, $matches);
```

Should do what you want. `$matches` will be an array with each match.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want words as values in the array:

```
$words  = explode(' ', $string);
$result = preg_grep('/\[[^\]]+\]/', $words);
$others = array_diff($words, $result);
```

- Create an array of words using `explode()` on a space
- Use a regex to find `[somethings]` using `preg_grep()`
- Find the difference of all words and `[somethings]` using `array_diff()`, which will be the "other" parts of the string